# ошибка в при подключении расписания к кнопке пункта меню. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

После запуска приложения , и при нажатии кнопки "Look Raspisanie" вылетает ошибка :

```
   Can not set 
javafx.scene.control.TableView field ch.makery.address.view.RaspisaniePrepodOwerview.raspisanieTable 
to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
```

Помогите  пожалуйста ее исправить!
Код программ:

```
package ch.makery.address.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class RaspisanieStudentOwerview {
    @FXML
    private Label labelTitle;
    @FXML
    private Label time1;

    @FXML
    private Label time2;
    @FXML
    private Label time3;
    @FXML
    private Label time4;
    @FXML
    private Label time5;
    @FXML
    private Label time6;
    @FXML
    private Label labelnedelya;

    @FXML
    private Label nechet1;
    @FXML
    private Label nechet2;
    @FXML
    private Label nechet3;
    @FXML
    private Label nechet4;
    @FXML
    private Label nechet5;
    @FXML
    private Label nechet6;
    @FXML
    private Label chet1;
    @FXML
    private Label chet2;
    @FXML
    private Label chet3;
    @FXML
    private Label chet4;
    @FXML
    private Label chet5;
    @FXML
    private Label chet6;

    @FXML
    private Label ponedelnik;
    @FXML
    private Label vtornik;
    @FXML
    private Label sreda;
    @FXML
    private Label chhetverg;
    @FXML
    private Label pyatnica;
    @FXML
    private Label subbota;

    @FXML
    private Label arhis1;
    @FXML
    private Label arhis2;
    @FXML
    private Label arhis3;
    @FXML
    private Label arhis4;
    @FXML
    private Label arhis5;
    @FXML
    private Label arhis6;

    @FXML
    private Label trs1;
    @FXML
    private Label trs2;
    @FXML
    private Label trs3;
    @FXML
    private Label trs4;
    @FXML
    private Label trs5;
    @FXML
    private Label tspp;
    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */ 
    public RaspisanieStudentOwerview(){}
}
```

Fxml файл :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ch.makery.address.view.RaspisanieStudentOwerview">
   <children>
      <GridPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="48.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="60.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="60.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="time1" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  08:30" />
            <Label fx:id="time2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  10:10" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="time3" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="54.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  11:50" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="time4" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="89.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  14:00" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label fx:id="time5" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  15:40" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label fx:id="time6" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="159.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="  17:20" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <GridPane layoutX="65.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="261.0" prefWidth="595.0">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="65.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="62.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="82.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="81.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="86.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="98.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="84.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="93.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="92.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="94.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="92.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="94.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="76.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="arhis1" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet1" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="chet1" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="chet2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="33.0" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label fx:id="chet3" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="75.0" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label fx:id="chet4" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="118.0" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label fx:id="chet5" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="147.0" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
            <Label fx:id="chet6" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="180.0" text="chet" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet3" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet4" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet5" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Label fx:id="nechet6" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="11.0" text="nechet" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <Label fx:id="arhis2" layoutX="67.0" layoutY="12.0" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="arhis3" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="32.0" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label fx:id="arhis4" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="153.0" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label fx:id="arhis5" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="174.0" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Label fx:id="arhis6" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="174.0" text="Arhis " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
            <Label fx:id="trs1" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="112.0" text="TRSiPV " GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label fx:id="trs2" text="TRSiPV " GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label fx:id="trs3" text="TRSiPV " GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label fx:id="labelnedelya" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="32.0" text="nendelya" />
            <Label fx:id="ponedelnik" text="Ponedelnik" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label fx:id="vtornik" text="Vtornik" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <Label fx:id="sreda" text="Sreda" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
            <Label fx:id="chhetverg" text="Chetverg" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
            <Label fx:id="pyatnica" text="Pyatinca" GridPane.columnIndex="5" />
            <Label fx:id="subbota" text="Subbota" GridPane.columnIndex="6" />
            <Label fx:id="trs4" text="TRSiPV " GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label fx:id="trs5" text="TSPP" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label fx:id="tspp" layoutX="335.0" layoutY="152.0" text="TRSiPV" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <Label fx:id="labelTitle" layoutX="273.0" layoutY="14.0" scaleX="2.0" scaleY="2.0" text="Rasspisanie Zanyatiu" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Файл StudentRootController:

```
package ch.makery.address.view;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import ch.makery.address.StudentMainApp;


public class StudentRootController {

    StudentMainApp studentmainapp = new StudentMainApp();
       /**
          * Opens the Ghurnal Ocenok.
          */  
           public void handleGhurnalOcenokShow(){
               studentmainapp.showCurrentOcenkiStudent();
           }

      /**
          * Open Create Lections.
          */  
          public void handleShowLectionsShow(){
              studentmainapp.ShowLectionsController();
           }

          /**
              * Open Look Raspisanie.
              */  
              public void handleShowRaspisanieShow(){
                  studentmainapp.ShowRaspisanieController();
               }

                       public void FileClose(){
                           System.exit(0);
                       }
}
```

файл STudentOwerWiew Controller:

```
package ch.makery.address.view;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import ch.makery.address.MainApp;
import ch.makery.address.StudentMainApp;
import ch.makery.address.model.Test;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class StudentOverviewController {
    @FXML
    public TextArea taTestStud;
    @FXML
    public Label  labelTest;

       @FXML
        private Button butExportTest;//save
        @FXML
        private Button butImportTest;//look


    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public StudentOverviewController() {

    }




    public void FileOpen(){
           JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
           fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");                
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    FileRead(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace(System.err); 
                }
          }
       }


       public void FileSave(){
           JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
           fileopen.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Сохранить в файл");                
            if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    FileWrite(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                }
            }
        }



           public void FileWrite(String Filename)throws IOException{
                FileWriter f = new FileWriter(Filename);

                for(Test tst : StudentMainApp.getTestList()){

                    f.write(tst.TestList.getValue() + "\r\n");
                }

                f.close();
            }

           public void FileRead(String Filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{         
               StudentMainApp.getTestList().clear();            

                Scanner fin = new Scanner(new File(Filename));  
                String test = "";

                while(fin.hasNextLine())
                {
                    if(StudentMainApp.getTestList().size()>0){
                        test += fin.nextLine() + "\r\n";
                    }

                    StudentMainApp.getTestList().add(new Test(
                              new SimpleStringProperty(test) ));

                }       
                fin.close();    
                taTestStud.setPromptText(test);
            }
}
```

Файл StudentMain APP:

```
package ch.makery.address;

import java.io.IOException;

import ch.makery.address.model.GhurnalOcenok;
import ch.makery.address.model.Lections;
import ch.makery.address.model.Test;
//import ch.makery.address.view.TestController;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
//import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StudentMainApp extends Application {

     private Stage studentStage;
        private BorderPane rootLayout;

        //коллекция
        private static ObservableList<GhurnalOcenok> ghurnalocenokData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        private static ObservableList<Test> testData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        private static ObservableList<Lections> lekciiData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public static ObservableList<GhurnalOcenok> getGhurnalOcenokList() {
            return ghurnalocenokData;

        }

        public static ObservableList<Test> getTestList() {
            return testData;

        }
        public static ObservableList<Lections> getLectionList() {
            return lekciiData ;

        }

        public StudentMainApp() {
            // Add some sample data
            //table
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage studentStage ) {
            this.studentStage = studentStage;
            this.studentStage.setTitle("TCPP:Student");

            initRootLayout();
            showTestOverview();

        }

        /**
         * Initializes the root layout.
         */
        public void initRootLayout() {
            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/StudentLayout.fxml"));
                rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

                // Show the scene containing the root layout.
                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                studentStage.setScene(scene);
                studentStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        /**
         * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
         */
        public void showTestOverview() {
            try {
                // Load person overview.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/StudentOverviewController.fxml"));// view/PrepodOverviewController.fxml
                AnchorPane studentOverview = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
                rootLayout.setCenter(studentOverview);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the main stage.
         * @return
         */
        public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
            return studentStage;
        }


    public void ShowLectionsController() {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(PrepodMainApp.class.getResource("view/Lekcui.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Lekcionnuy Material");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(studentStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the persons into the controller.
            //TestController controller = loader.getController();

            //controller.setOcenkiData( ghurnalocenokData);

            dialogStage.show();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }

    }



    public void ShowRaspisanieController() {
         try {
                // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(PrepodMainApp.class.getResource("view/Raspisaniye.fxml"));
                AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                dialogStage.setTitle("Raspisanie_Prepoda");
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                dialogStage.initOwner(studentStage);
                Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);



                dialogStage.show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }
        }



    public void showCurrentOcenkiStudent() {
         try {
                // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/Current Ocenki Studenta.fxml"));//
                AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)loader.load();

                Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
                dialogStage.setTitle("Current Ocenki for all learning year");
                dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                dialogStage.initOwner(studentStage);
                Scene scene = new Scene(page);
                dialogStage.setScene(scene);

                // Set the persons into the controller.
                //BarChartStatisticController controller = loader.getController();

                //controller.setOcenkiData( ghurnalocenokData);

                dialogStage.show();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();   
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```